# Elements in Scrolling Div with Fixed Background Gradient

Tags: html, css, scroll, gradient

I have a scrolling div with elements that have a fixed background gradient.

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90vh;
}
#header {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
#body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, purple) fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

The codepen is here:

https://codepen.io/swards/pen/XavVpz

It seems like a bug with webkit, as this is pretty straightforward and works in Safari.  Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: I'll leave this up for now, but It looks like this issue may have been fixed in the latest Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100.